# $C_{[a,b]} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x(t) \mapsto f(x) = \int_a^b x(t)dt$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> Problem: Prove that $f:C_{[a,b]} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x(t) \mapsto f(x) = \displaystyle\int_a^b x(t)dt$ is continuous.

**My opinion:**

Let $x, x' \in C_{[a,b]}$, so they are bounded and we can choose a $\delta >0$ such that $d(x,x') < \delta$. To prove that $f$ is continuous we have to prove $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : d(x,x') < \delta \Rightarrow d(f(x),f(x') < \epsilon$

My queston: with $f(x), f(x')$, how can we find a $\epsilon > 0$
respectively? Thank all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$ \left|f(x)-f(x')\right|=\left|\int_a^b x(t)-x'(t) \, dt \right|
\leq \int_a^b \left| x(t)-x'(t) \right| \,dt \leq (b-a)\sup_{t \in [a,b]} \left| x(t)-x'(t) \right|. $$

Comment: I know this corollary, but we are working in $C_{[a,b]}$ with metric is $d(x,x') = \max |x(t) - x'(t)|$ and $\max |x(t) - x'(t)| \leq \sup |x(t) - x'(t)|$, so I don't know how to choose $\epsilon, \delta$.

Comment: @Minh Continuous functions attain their extrema on compact sets, so $\max = \sup$ for this space.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define $d(x,x')$ in order to be able to find your $\epsilon$ accordingly.

For example if you define $$d(x,x')= \max _{t\in [a,b]} \{ |x(t)-x'(t)|\}$$ then $$|f(x)-f(x')|\le (b-a)d(x,x')$$

so you can find your $\delta$ if an $\epsilon$  is given.

Comment: Accordingly your hint, I choose $\epsilon = \delta = b d(x,x')$, so $|f(x) - f(x')| < b d(x,x')$ and $d(x,x') < b d(x,x')$. But I think this is not true, because $\epsilon, \delta$ are not constant numbers

Comment: take $\delta=\epsilon /(b-a)$ and go from there.

Comment: Given $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(x')| < \epsilon$, from $|f(x) - f(x')| \leq (b-a) d(x,x') < \epsilon$. Let $\delta = \epsilon/(b-a)$, so $d(x,x') < \delta$.